# AngularJS ng-style with a conditional expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am handling my issue like this:

```
ng-style="{ width: getTheValue() }"
```

But to avoid having this function on the controller side, I would much prefer to do something like this:

```
ng-style="{ width: myObject.value == 'ok' ? '100%' : '0%' }"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what version of angular are you using? At least with 1.1.5 this is possible without any changes. [demo](http://jsbin.com/ATuqaqa/1/)

Comment: I am using 1.0.8 :) Oh too bad, I should really try to upgrade then... thanks!

Comment: Although that with 1.1.5 your code is working, if you use other style properties instead of width (e.g. font-size) your code won't work until you change it to: ng-style="{ **'font-size'**: myObject.value == 'ok' ? '20px' : '10px' }" (must surround the style property with quotes).

Comment: I dont know this is helpful but for new comers you can use ng style with an object but like this                                                                         ng-style="objectBit ? { 'border':'1px solid red'} : { 'border': 'none' }"

Answer (score 127, accepted):

As @Yoshi said, from angular 1.1.5 you can use-it without any change.

If you use angular < 1.1.5, you can use [ng-class](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass).

```
.largeWidth {
    width: 100%;
}

.smallWidth {
    width: 0%;
}

// [...]

ng-class="{largeWidth: myVar == 'ok', smallWidth: myVar != 'ok'}"
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! I just wondered if there was a way to do it without using any classes, but everything directly using Angular on the template.

Comment: ng-style is much faster than ng-class. If you have a large DOM with lots of conditionals it will be noticeable. Nevertheless this is clean.

Comment: How to use this for more than one class names ?

Comment: And if I'm using angular >1.1.5 ?

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question.

Comment: This question literally asks for an example with ng-style and the accepted answer with 100+ votes does not provide that.

Comment: this is the wrong answer, the answer from @Arthur below is correct.

Answer (score 400):

simple example:

```
<div ng-style="isTrue && {'background-color':'green'} || {'background-color': 'blue'}" style="width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid gray;"></div>
```

{'background-color':'green'} RETURN true

OR the same result:

```
<div ng-style="isTrue && {'background-color':'green'}" style="width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid gray;background-color: blue"></div>
```

other conditional possibility:

```
<div ng-style="count === 0 && {'background-color':'green'}  || count === 1 && {'background-color':'yellow'}" style="width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid gray;background-color: blue"></div>
```

Comment: How might I accomplish this but with multiple independent styles/conditions?  Thanks, great answer btw.

Comment: @Arthur your example is going to check `isTrue ` and `{'background-color':'green'}`  OR it is going to check only `isTrue` and will put `background `  how it will work please explain anyone?

Comment: @rajnish-rajput it is going to check isTrue and put background, {'background-color':'green'} by default return true as a style object

Comment: This does indeed work, but the syntax is really weird. Any links to documentation of this or any input on why it works with &&- and ||-operators?

Comment: @ArthurTsidkilov what if I want to restrict `ng-style` to run only once? I can't use `ng-class` and controller scope variable, I need to calculate all containers heights at runtime but once a property is set I want to restrict it to avoid continues execution.

Answer (score 122):

You can achieve it like that:

```
ng-style="{ 'width' : (myObject.value == 'ok') ? '100%' : '0%' }"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It actually uses ng-style and allows for conditionals for each style.

Answer (score 46):

@jfredsilva obviously has [the simplest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32245636/796127) for the question:

> ng-style="{ 'width' : (myObject.value == 'ok') ? '100%' : '0%' }"

**However, you might really want to consider my answer for something more complex.**

Ternary-like example:

```
<p ng-style="{width: {true:'100%',false:'0%'}[myObject.value == 'ok']}"></p>
```

Something more complex:

```
<p ng-style="{
   color:       {blueish: 'blue', greenish: 'green'}[ color ], 
  'font-size':  {0: '12px', 1: '18px', 2: '26px'}[ zoom ]
}">Test</p>
```

If `$scope.color == 'blueish'`, the color will be 'blue'.

If `$scope.zoom == 2`, the font-size will be 26px.

```js
angular.module('app',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.color = 'blueish';
  $scope.zoom = 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-style="{
   color:       {blueish: 'blue', greenish: 'green'}[ color ], 
  'font-size':  {0: '12px', 1: '18px', 2: '26px'}[ zoom ]
}">
  color = {{color}}<br>
  zoom = {{zoom}}
</div>
```

Comment: interesting syntax `{<value>:'<string>'}[<$scope.var>]}`, where it come from?

Comment: It's just using bracket notation to access the object. `color['blueish'] == 'blue'`

Answer (score 11):

if you want use with expression, the rigth way is :

```
<span class="ng-style: yourCondition && {color:'red'};">Sample Text</span>
```

but the best way is using ng-class

Comment: `Syntax Error: Token '%3A' is%20an%20unexpected%20token at column 9 of the expression [ng-style%3A%`...

Answer (score 10):

On a generic note, you can use a combination of `ng-if` and `ng-style` incorporate conditional changes with change in background image.

```
<span ng-if="selectedItem==item.id"
              ng-style="{'background-image':'url(../images/'+'{{item.id}}'+'_active.png)','background-size':'52px 57px','padding-top':'70px','background-repeat':'no-repeat','background-position': 'center'}"></span>
        <span ng-if="selectedItem!=item.id"
              ng-style="{'background-image':'url(../images/'+'{{item.id}}'+'_deactivated.png)','background-size':'52px 57px','padding-top':'70px','background-repeat':'no-repeat','background-position': 'center'}"></span>
```

Comment: This caused `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ng-style' since it isn't a known property of 'div'` error for me

Answer (score 7):

For single css property

```
ng-style="1==1 && {'color':'red'}"
```

For multiple css properties below can be referred

```
ng-style="1==1 && {'color':'red','font-style': 'italic'}"
```

Replace 1==1 with your condition expression

Answer (score 5):

also this syntax for ternary operator will work:

```
  ng-style="<$scope.var><condition> ? {
        '<css-prop-1>':((<value>) / (<value2>)*100)+'%',
        '<css-prop-2>':'<string>'
      } : {
        '<css-prop-1>':'<string>',
        '<css-prop-2>':'<string>'
      }"
```

where `<value>` are $scope property values.
In example:

```
ng-style="column.histograms.value=>0 ? 
  {
    'width':((column.histograms.value) / (column.histograms.limit)*100)+'%',
    'background':'#F03040'
  } : {
    'width':'1px',
    'background':'#2E92FA'
  }"
```

```

this allows for some calculaton into the css property values.

Answer (score 5):

I am doing like below for multiple and independent conditions and it works like charm:

```
<div ng-style="{{valueFromJS}} === 'Hello' ? {'color': 'red'} : {'color': ''} && valueFromNG-Repeat === '{{dayOfToday}}' ? {'font-weight': 'bold'} : {'font-weight': 'normal'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

### EDIT:

Ok i was previously not aware that `AngularJS` usually refers to `Angular` v1 version and only Angular to Angular v2+

This answer only applies for `Angular`

Leaving this here for future reference..

---

Not sure how it works for you guys but on Angular 9 i have to wrap ngStyle in brackets like this:

```
[ng-style]="{ 'width' : (myObject.value == 'ok') ? '100%' : '0%' }"
```

Otherwise it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I am using ng-class for adding style :-

```
 ng-class="column.label=='Description'  ? 'tableStyle':                     
           column.label == 'Markdown Type' ? 'Mtype' : 
           column.label == 'Coupon Number' ? 'couponNur' :  ''
           "
```

Using ***ternary operator*** along with ng-class directives in ***angular.js*** for giving style.
Then define the style for class in **.css** or **.scss** file. Eg :-

```
.Mtype{
       width: 90px !important;
       min-width: 90px !important;
       max-width: 90px !important;
      }
.tableStyle{
         width: 129px !important;
         min-width: 129px !important;
         max-width: 129px !important;
}
.couponNur{
         width: 250px !important;
         min-width: 250px !important;
         max-width: 250px !important;
}
```