# Dynamically set the background color of mat-tab

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to be able to set the color of the tab according to a condition like i'm doing on the div in the provided stackblitz project with the content class. If the `selectedMarketStatus === marketStatus.Open` statement is true i want both the content div and the tab to be green. Is this possible? If so how do i do it?

Edit: updated the blitz which kind of does what i wanted, the scss style on the &-closed does not work on stackblitz but it works in my project.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5jtkr3-abyl6r?file=app%2Ftab-group-theme-example.html)

```js
export class TabGroupThemeExample {
  public marketStatus = MarketPurchaseStatus;
  public selectedMarketStatus = this.marketStatus.Open;
  constructor() {}
}

export enum MarketPurchaseStatus {
  BeforeOpen = 0,
    Open = 1,
    AfterClose = 2
}
```

```css
.content {
  background-color: gray;
}

.open {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<mat-tab-group class="subscription-market-tabs" [animationDuration]="0" [disableRipple]="true">
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>aaaa</ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab [disabled]="selectedMarketStatus === marketStatus.AfterClosed">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>bbbb</ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
<div class="content" [class.open]="selectedMarketStatus === marketStatus.Open">aaaaaa</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional Styling to achieve this. i believe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31917600/2148050) will help you.

If you add style:

```
<some-element [ngStyle]="{'backgroundColor':  (selectedMarketStatus === marketStatus.Open) ? 'green' : ''}">element</some-element>
```

If you have a class like above use the below code:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'green': selectedMarketStatus === marketStatus.Open }">...</some-element>
```

Please look at angular documentation for [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) and [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

Please look at this updated version of your [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5jtkr3-abyl6r)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this does not seem to work on the Mat-tab element? Nothing is happening.

Comment: I can't see any changes on the link you sent?

Comment: I can use this on other elements as usual but my problem is that i cant get it done on the mat-tab element.

Comment: Please look at this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5jtkr3-abyl6r)

Comment: Nice, well i got that to work as well but then only the text in the tab gets a new background color, I need the full tab to change color.

Comment: That's more to do with how you write css, or the width/height of the tab. But the code would remain same as above.

Comment: I can select the tab but i don't know hos to dynamically change it. Check out the new css file. [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5jtkr3-abyl6r)

Comment: Could you explain, what do you mean, when you say dynamically change it? do you want to listen to a tab change event? Or do you want to change the color of your tab?

Comment: Well the dynamic thing is not that important right now, the thing is that it does not seem to be possible to change the Mat-tab element with a condition, just the text in the ng-template

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a way to add multiple tabs, with dynamic content. Have you looked at [tabs documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples) they also have stackblitz links.

Comment: No just to change the background color of the tab.

Comment: I have added some further content in the tab to show the tab takes the height of its content,  or you can specify the minimum height of the tab, does that help with your problem?

Comment: Hehe thats relay nice :D but i need the green of the tab to take up the full tab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200891/discussion-between-zonaib-and-johannes-kraft).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a global style for the tabs and used parent selectors to create one style that was "Open" and one that was "Closed" then i could conditionally switch between the two in the component.

Also updated the blitz in my original post.

`tab-styles.scss:`

```css
.subscription-market-tabs {
  &-open {
    /* Removes the bottom border below the tabs */
    .mat-tab-header {
      border-bottom: none;
      /** Hack to hide the border between .mat-tab-body-wrapper and the active tab */
      transform: translateY(1px);
      z-index: 1000;
    }
    // Styling of tabs in the top banner (on the right side) of a coordinet-component
    .mat-tab-list {
      // Remove underline
      mat-ink-bar.mat-ink-bar {
        display: none;
      }
      // Tabs with rounded corners.
      .mat-tab-labels {
        color: black; // TODO: theme color
        .mat-tab-label {
          height: 72px;
          padding: 0 48px;
          border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
          background-color: #F2F8FF;
          color: black;
          border: 1px solid #D0DCEA;
          font-weight: 600;
          &.mat-tab-label-active {
            border-bottom: none;
            min-width: 160px !important;
            background-color: #D6ECEC; // TODO: theme color
            color: black; // TODO: theme color
            opacity: 1;
            font-weight: 700;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  &-closed {
    /* Removes the bottom border below the tabs */
    .mat-tab-header {
      border-bottom: none;
      /** Hack to hide the border between .mat-tab-body-wrapper and the active tab */
      transform: translateY(1px);
      z-index: 1000;
    }
    // Styling of tabs in the top banner (on the right side) of a coordinet-component
    .mat-tab-list {
      // Remove underline
      mat-ink-bar.mat-ink-bar {
        display: none;
      }
      // Tabs with rounded corners.
      .mat-tab-labels {
        color: black; // TODO: theme color
        .mat-tab-label {
          height: 72px;
          padding: 0 48px;
          border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
          background-color: #F2F8FF;
          color: black;
          border: 1px solid #D0DCEA;
          font-weight: 600;
          &.mat-tab-label-active {
            border-bottom: none;
            min-width: 160px !important;
            background-color: #E7F0FA; // TODO: theme color
            color: black; // TODO: theme color
            opacity: 1;
            font-weight: 700;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<mat-tab-group [class.subscription-market-tabs-closed]="model.selectedMarketStatus === marketStatus.AfterClose || marketStatus.BeforeOpen" 
                [class.subscription-market-tabs-open]="model.selectedMarketStatus === marketStatus.Open"
                [animationDuration]="0">
  <mat-tab [label]="'forecast-and-subscriptions-tab'|translate">
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab [label]="'market-and-bid-list-tab'|translate">
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```