# Angular JS - Conditional inline style with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I would like to display styles which depend on dynamic values conditionally. For example:

```
<div ng-style="!obj.prop ? 'width : 0;' : 'width: {{ obj.val1 / obj.val2 }}%;'"></div>
```

Is this possible to do using ng-class or ng-style?

Comment: You don't need interpolation `{{` and `}}` inside `ng-style`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular ng-style with a conditional expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375695/angular-ng-style-with-a-conditional-expression)

Answer (score 1):

Use this refactored version and you would be fine:

```
<div ng-style="{ 'width' : !obj.prop ? 0 : obj.val1 / obj.val2 + '%' }"></div>
```

Your problem was that you were using interpolation (`{{` and `}}`) inside a directive which requires an expression.

**As a good rule of thumb, remember that most built-in AngularJS directives require an expression and not interpolation**. A few directives which work with interpolation: [ngHref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref), [ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc).