# Apply ng-style only if this data exists

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a page with Angular and trying to conditionally apply ng-style to a div only if 'cover' is defined in my data resource. `{{data.cover}}` renders the cover image URL in the template. I tried the code below but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="cover" ng-style="{'background-image: url({{data.cover}})':data.cover}"></div>
```

**UPDATE:** This is the solution I came up with, adding this in the controller (I needed to do the same thing for the user cover and avatar):

```
var cover = $scope.data.cover; 
var avatar = $scope.data.user.image; 

if (typeof $scope.data.cover !== "undefined") { 
    $scope.coverImage = { 'background-image': 'url('+cover+')' }; 
} 

if (typeof $scope.data.avatar !== "undefined") { 
    $scope.avatarImage = { 'background-image': 'url('+avatar+')' }; 
}
```

In the HTML template:

```
<div class="cover" ng-style="coverImage"></div>
<div class="avatar" ng-style="avatarImage"></div>
```

Although I'm not sure if this would be considered DOM manipulation that should be handled via a directive and not a controller? Seemed much simpler to do this in the controller rather than a separate directive.

Comment: I've edited my answer so it's supposed to work

Answer (score 0):

According to [Angular ng-style with a conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375695/angular-ng-style-with-a-conditional-expression) I would use this syntaxe :

```
<div class="cover" ng-style="coverExist() && {'background-image': 'url({{data.cover}})'}"></div>
```

With a method that does return true if the variable exist, either it returns false, see the following :

```
$scope.coverExist = function()
    { 
if (typeof $scope.data.cover == "undefined") return false;
else
return true; 
}
```

You may ask, why a method while I could have test that data.cover just got a "truhly" value.
If you ever need to change the condition, for example, you set it only if it got a certain size/resolution, whatever, just change the method behavior and keep the "true" and "false" return based on your condition.

Comment: This gives me some sort of syntax error----> Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$parse/syntax?p0=(&p1=is[object Object]nexpected%C%expecting%%5B%A%D&p2=12&p3=%BcoverExist()%%26%%20'background-image%A%url()'%D&p4=()%%26%%20'background-image%A%url()'%D

Comment: ( I am actually using `{[{data.cover}]}` or `{[{value}]}` for start/end symbols so `{{value}}` doesn't interfere with my django template tags, if that makes any difference... )

Comment: @annieXo Edited ! I tried it on my own website, it works with angular only, try it

Comment: @annieXo edited again so it match your variable name.

Comment: Still not working for me. In the browser inspector I see: `<div class="cover" ng-style="coverExist() && {'background-image':'url(https://path.to/path-to-image.png)'}" style="background-image:url("");">` as if it's able to get `data.cover` but can't insert it in the style attribute... hmm. (thanks for your help!)

Comment: @annieXo Wait, you don't have  the "style="background-image:url("");" part in your code, do you ?

Comment: No, I used your code. This is what I see when I load the page in the browser inspector. I assume it's showing the style attribute that is added by the coverExist() function but it seems to be showing that it gets added without the `data.cover` as the URL.

Comment: Can you do a console.log(data.cover) in the coverExist method ?

Comment: I think it's clear the function is able to find `data.cover` since it shows in the code I posted above from the console, and it is only defined in that function, not elsewhere in the DOM. For now I switched to simply using a data-attribute (`data-cover`) on the element with `{{data.cover}}` as its value and using jQuery to apply that as the background image if the data-attribute has a value.

Comment: @annieXo yeah pretty obvious.. I was tired sorry. Well.. Can you post your controller ?

Comment: No worries, I appreciate your help! I just updated the post with the solution I came up with. Not sure if it's the most ideal but it's what I was able to get to work when other solutions failed.

Comment: Well, it works, nice done ! Still surprised that my answer does not work for while it works on my test :'(

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```php
ng-style="data.cover && {'background-image: url({{data.cover}})'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="cover" ng-style="!!data.cover && {'background-image: url({{data.cover}})'}"></div>
```