# AngularJS Conditional ngStyle not applying

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, conditional-statements, directive

I am trying to make my input width respond to an AngularJS scope variable, by setting it's width conditionally with ng-style. I have gotten this to work beautifully with text-align, but for some reason it is not working with width...

The HTML:

```
<body ng-app="vfApp">
    <!--This works...  --> <input resize ng-style="{ 'width' : '100%' }" type="text"/>
    <!--This does not?!--> <input resize ng-style="{ 'width' : doResize ? '100%' : '10%' }" type="text"/>
</body>
```

The JS:

```
var vfApp = angular.module('vfApp', []);
vfApp.directive('resize', function () {
    return function ($scope) {
        $scope.doResize = false;
    };
});
```

EDIT:
This is different from the suggested possible duplicate because I am not trying to apply a static CSS class, I am trying to use a variable to conditionally apply a style inline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular ng-style with a conditional expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375695/angular-ng-style-with-a-conditional-expression)

Comment: the solutions are different enough that it could not be a duplicate, though I'm not positive if that's enough to differentiate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using Angular 1.0.1. You can use this:

```
ng-style="doResize && {'width':'100%'} || {'width':'10%'}"
```

See demo below:

```js
var vfApp = angular.module('vfApp', []);
vfApp.directive('resize', function($window) {
  return function($scope) {
    $scope.doResize = true;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="vfApp">
  <!--This works...-->
  <input resize ng-style="{ 'width' : '100%' }" type="text" />
  <!--This does not?!-->
  <input resize ng-style="doResize && {'width':'100%'} || {'width':'10%'}" type="text" />

  <br/>isMobile value: {{doResize}}

</body>
```

Comment: @KenSchnetz let me know your feedback on this, thanks!

Comment: Perfect... what's wierd to me is that the way was doing it in my JSFiddle works with text-alignment no problem, but it doesn't work for width. Your solution however works great!! 

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming for the `100% width` value, the problem is simple the `ternary expression`:

```
doResize ? '100%' : '10%'.
```

in your js file `doResize` is false. If you don't understand ternary expressions, they are a condensed if. The uncompressed form of your code is:

```
if(doResize) {
  return '100%';
} else {
  return '10%';
}
```

So you have two options to fix it:

1. Change `$scope.doResize = false;` to `$scope.doResize = true;`
2. Change the `ternary expression` to `doResize ? '10%' : '100%';`

Hope that helps.

Comment: I understand the doResize is false, I condensed my overall code to solve this problem before implementing it in my website. 

Also, the problem isnt that I am not getting the 100% width, i'm not getting the 10% width either. 

Thank you for your time!

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: Please don't be sorry, I probably didn't explain it well enough!! Thank you so much for your time.