# Add multiple condition in the ng-style

Tags: angularjs

I need to add multiple condition in the `ng-style`.
How can I do this?

I tried below code but it is not working.

```
ng-style="ifTrue?'opacity:1;' : 'ifTrue? 'opacity: 1;': 'opacity: 0.5;''"
```

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375695/angular-ng-style-with-a-conditional-expression

Answer (score 4):

You can simply separate your conditions with ",".
Something like this:

`ng-style="{ 'background-color': '#ff0', color: 'red' }"`

See this example: http://jsbin.com/fabisepede/edit?html,output

---

Always remember to put quotes on "dashed" word ('background-color').

For the value you can also use variables defined in your controller and assign the style conditionally, but for that i prefer ng-class.

Comment: did you understand the OP's problem?

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like

`ng-style="condition && { /*properties*/ } || condition2 && { /*other properties*/ }"`

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
ng-style="IfCondition1 ? checkAnotherCondition && {'color':'red'} : {'color': 'green','font-weight':'bolder'}"
```

It checks my first condition and if true then it checks another condition and if that is true it makes it red.   If the first condition is false then the last style is applied.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-style="ifTrue ? 'opacity:1;' : 'opacity: 0.5;'`

`ng-style=(condition) ? 'run this if true' : 'run this if false'`

Why dont use something like this?

Comment: `ifTrue` was just a notation, OP has multiple conditions.

Answer (score 0):

how to set for three condition
example:

`if data is === 1 then red`

`if data is === 2 then blue`

else pink

Answer (score 0):

@mario - you can use something like

```html
[ngStyle]="{'property-to-set': (if_1) ? (true_block_1) : ((if_2) ? (true_block_2) : (other_true))}
```