# How to apply a dynamic value in ng-style conditionally?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I would like to apply a `background-color` with `ng-style` conditionally **when the color value can be updated from `$scope`**.

Here are my variables in scope:

```
$scope.someone = { id: '1', name: 'John', color: '#42a1cd' };
$scope.mainId = 1;
```

Actually I don't use any condition to apply the background color, it is done with:

```
<div ng-style="{'background-color': someone.color}">
    {{someone.name}}
</div>
```

---

The idea here is to apply this background color **only when `someone.id == mainId`**. I tried several solutions, but it does not seems to be the correct synthax:

- `ng-style="{{someone.id == mainId}} ? ('background-color': {{someone.color}}) : null"`
- `ng-style="{ ('background-color': someone.color) : someone.id == mainId }"`

---

### [JSFiddle for testing](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/fgc21e86/6/)

Does someone have an idea of how I can achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular ng-style with a conditional expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375695/angular-ng-style-with-a-conditional-expression)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think it is not a duplicate, as in your link the value of the style is **hard-coded**, and not **coming from scope**.

Comment: So? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32245636/447356) is 100% the same as the accepted answer here, just replace the static values in there with the scope values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to work fine.

```
ng-style="{'background-color': person.id === mainId ? person.color : ''}"
```

See updated fiddle with two people - the one with `mainId` has a background color, while the other doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/fgc21e86/7/

Comment: @TorbjørnAngeltveit I think [@Ashish answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41870728/4927984) is what you are talking about.

Comment: @Mistalis Yeah, sorry. Was a bit quick on the trigger.

Answer (score 4):

You may try like this

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-style="{'background-color': getColor(someone)}">
    {{someone.name}}
  </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.someone = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
    color: '#42a1cd'
  };
  $scope.getColor = function(someone) {

        if($scope.mainId === someone.id) {
        return someone.color;
      }
  }
  $scope.mainId = 1;
}]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do it like

```
ng-style="someone.id == mainId ? {'background-color':'{{someone.color}}'} : {'background-color':'red'}"
```

Here's an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fgc21e86/9/