# Conditional css page in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

When creating an angular component, how can make the css file conditional. ie., say for example, if I want style1.css when the user.type = 'A' and style2.css when user.type='B'. Is this possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375695/angular-ng-style-with-a-conditional-expression

Comment: @AdityaMukherji that is about angularjs, not related to angular2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with code that is like this:

main `index.html`

```
<head>
   <link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" href="firstsheet.css">
</head>
```

Then your component code would look like this

```
@Component({
   ........
})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }

    switchTheme() {
      this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', 'secondsheet.css');
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this affect the whole DOM? or just the component's style?
I was looking at something like.

`@Component({
  selector: 'app-items-list',
  templateUrl: './items-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ if (something) :'./items-list.component.css'?'./items-list.component2.css' ]
})`

Comment: No, this solution only works for the whole DOM. Because of the way view encapsulation works at the component level, the CSS classes get renamed arbitrarily (to enable encapsulation) so there is no way to replace them programmatically